# Project Euler problem 92 - square digit chains

Tags: python, optimization, project-euler

[Link to problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=92).

> A number chain is created by continuously adding the square of the
>   digits in a number to form a new number until it has been seen before.
>
> For example,
>
> 44 -> 32 -> 13 -> 10 -> 1 -> 1
>
> 85 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> 4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89
>
> Therefore any chain that arrives at 1 or 89 will become stuck in an
>   endless loop. What is most amazing is that EVERY starting number will
>   eventually arrive at 1 or 89.
>
> How many starting numbers below ten million will arrive at 89?

This solution to Project Euler problem 92 takes about 80 seconds. How can I reduce the time to well under 60 seconds?

```
def squareDigits(num):
    total = 0
    for digit in str(num):
        total += int(digit) ** 2
    return total
pastChains = [None] * 10000001
pastChains[1], pastChains[89] = False, True
for num in range(2, 10000001):
    chain = [num]
    while pastChains[chain[-1]] is None:
        chain.append(squareDigits(chain[-1]))
    for term in chain:
        if pastChains[term] is not None:
            pastChains[term] = pastChains[chain[-1]]
print pastChains.count(True)
```

Comment: Memoization might help you

Comment: There is a nice combinatorial approach, described [here](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-92-square-digits-number-chain/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Bug

There's a bug in your program. This line

```
if pastChains[term] is not None:
```

should be

```
if pastChains[term] is None:
```

### 2. Piecewise improvement

In this section I'm going to show how you can speed up a program like this by making a series of small piecewise improvements. This doesn't often work for the Project Euler problems: normally you have to come up with new algorithmic ideas. But here you're pretty close to getting under the minute mark, and that makes piecewise improvement a plausible approach.

Note that I'm using Python 2.7 here, which is generally faster than Python 3.

#### 2.1. Base case

I'm going to start by putting your code into a form which is more convenien for testing (also, where we can run it for smaller limits than ten million, which can be convenient when making frequent measurement). Also, I'll improve the coding style while I'm about it (add docstrings; put local variables in `lower_case_with_underscores`; use the more meaningful values `1` and `89` instead of the Booleans `False` and `True`).

```
def square_digits(n):
    """Return the sum of squares of the base-10 digits of n."""
    total = 0
    for digit in str(n):
        total += int(digit) ** 2
    return total

def problem92a(limit):
    """Return the count of starting numbers below limit that eventually arrive
    at 89, as a result of iterating the sum-of-squares-of-digits.

    """
    arrive = [None] * limit # Number eventually arrived at, or None if unknown.
    arrive[1], arrive[89] = 1, 89
    for n in range(2, limit):
        chain = [n]
        while arrive[chain[-1]] is None:
            chain.append(square_digits(chain[-1]))
        for term in chain:
            if arrive[term] is None:
                arrive[term] = arrive[chain[-1]]
    return arrive.count(89)

>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:problem92a(10**7), number=1)
185.13595986366272
```

That's a lot slower than your reported "80 seconds": clearly you have a much faster machine than I do!

#### 2.2. Avoiding number/string conversion

Now, let's do some work on the `square_digits` function. As written, this function has to convert the integer `n` to a string and then convert each digit back to a number. We could avoid these conversions by working with numbers throughout:

```
def square_digits(n):
    """Return the sum of squares of the base-10 digits of n."""
    total = 0
    while n:
        total += (n % 10) ** 2
        n //= 10
    return total

>>> timeit(lambda:problem92a(10**7), number=1)
61.409788846969604
```

Nearly under the minute already!

#### 2.3. Second version

Here are some obvious minor improvements:

1. Avoid the repeated lookup of `chain[-1]` by remembering the value in a local variable.
2. Reduce the size of `chain` by one (because the last element in the chain is remembered in the local variable).
3. The test `arrive[term] is None` is unnecessary: by this point in the code we know that only the last term in `chain` was found in `arrive`.

That yields the following code:

```
def problem92b(limit):
    """Return the count of starting numbers below limit that eventually arrive
    at 89, as a result of iterating the sum-of-squares-of-digits.

    """
    arrive = [None] * limit # Number eventually arrived at, or None if unknown.
    arrive[1], arrive[89] = 1, 89
    for n in range(2, limit):
        chain = []
        while not arrive[n]:
            chain.append(n)
            n = square_digits(n)
        dest = arrive[n]
        for term in chain:
            arrive[term] = dest
    return arrive.count(89)
```

When transforming code like this, it's always important to check that our transformations didn't break anything. Here's where the ability to run the program for small values of `limit` comes in handy:

```
>>> all(problem92a(i) == problem92b(i) for i in range(1000, 2000))
True
```

And this yields a further 12% speedup:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:problem92b(10**7), number=1)
53.771003007888794
```

#### 2.3. Third version

The largest number under ten million is 9999999, whose sum of squares of digits is just 567. All other numbers in the range have even smaller sums of squares of digits. So for 568 and up, there is no need to follow the chain: we can just look up the answer directly. That suggests the following approach:

```
def problem92c(limit):
    """Return the count of starting numbers below limit that eventually arrive
    at 89, as a result of iterating the sum-of-squares-of-digits.

    """
    sum_limit = len(str(limit - 1)) * 9 ** 2 + 1
    arrive = [None] * sum_limit
    arrive[1], arrive[89] = 1, 89
    for n in range(2, sum_limit):
        chain = []
        while not arrive[n]:
            chain.append(n)
            n = square_digits(n)
        dest = arrive[n]
        for term in chain:
            arrive[term] = dest
    c = arrive.count(89)
    for n in range(sum_limit, limit):
        c += arrive[square_digits(n)] == 89
    return c
```

Again, we better check that we didn't break anything:

```
>>> all(problem92a(i) == problem92c(i) for i in range(1000, 2000))
True
```

And this yields a further 30% improvement:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:problem92c(10**7), number=1)
37.56105399131775
```

That's about an 80% speedup on the original version, just by making piecewise and localized improvements.

### 3. New algorithm

For more radical improvements to the runtime, we need to rethink the algorithm completely. Here's a sketch of the combinatorial approach:

For each number *k* up to 567 that arrives at 89, we work out all the ways to partition *k* into a sum of no more than seven squares from 1<sup>2</sup> to 9<sup>2</sup> (using the partitioning technique we used in our answer to [problem 76](http://projecteuler.net/problem=76), say). This gives us a multiset of digits, and we can use combinatorial techniques to count the number of ways this multiset can be realised as a number up to 9999999.

For example, the starting number 4 arrives at 89. 4 can be partitioned into 2<sup>2</sup> or into 1<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup>. In the first case, there are 7 starting numbers in the range (2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000, 200000 and 2000000). In the second case, writing C(*n*, *k*) for the number of combinations of *k* items out of *n*, there are C(3,3) + C(4,3) + C(5,3) + C(6,3) = 35 starting numbers in the range (1111, 10111, 11011, and so on).

And here's some code, which I hope is self-documenting! Ask if you don't understand anything.

It uses the [`@memoized` decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) from the [Python Decorator Library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) to avoid unnecessary re-computation.

```
from collections import Counter
from math import factorial
from memoize import memoized

@memoized
def partitions(n, k, v):
    """Return partitions of n into at most k items from v, with
    repetition. v must be a tuple sorted into numerical order. Each
    partition is returned as multiset in the form of a Counter object
    mapping items from v to the number of times they are used in the
    partition.

        >>> partitions(4, 7, (1, 4))
        [Counter({1: 4}), Counter({4: 1})]

    """
    if n == 0:
        # Base case: the empty partition.
        return [Counter()]
    if k == 0 or len(v) == 0 or n < v[0]:
        # No partitions possible here.
        return []
    pp = [p.copy() for p in partitions(n - v[0], k - 1, v)]
    for p in pp:
        p[v[0]] += 1
    return pp + partitions(n, k, v[1:])

@memoized
def multinomial(n, k):
    """Return the multinomial coefficient n! / k[0]! k[1]! ... k[m]!.

        >>> multinomial(6, (2, 2, 2))
        90

    """
    result = factorial(n)
    for i in k:
        result //= factorial(i)
    return result

@memoized
def number_count(digit_counts, min_digits, max_digits):
    """Return the count of numbers (with between min_digits and max_digits
    inclusive) whose distinct non-zero digits have counts given by the
    sequence digit_counts. For example if we have three identical
    non-zero digits and four digits in total:

        >>> number_count((3,), 4, 4)
        3

    because the possible numbers resemble 1011, 1101, and 1110.
    Similarly

        >>> number_count((1,1), 4, 4)
        6

    because the possible numbers resemble 1002, 1020, 1200, 2001,
    2010, and 2100.

    """
    nonzero_digits = sum(digit_counts)
    total = 0
    for digits in range(max(min_digits, nonzero_digits), max_digits + 1):
        for i, d in enumerate(digit_counts):
            counts = (digit_counts[:i] + (d - 1,) + digit_counts[i+1:]
                      + (digits - nonzero_digits,))
            total += multinomial(digits - 1, tuple(sorted(counts)))
    return total

def problem92d(limit):
    """Return the count of starting numbers below limit that eventually arrive
    at 89, as a result of iterating the sum-of-squares-of-digits.

    """
    max_digits = len(str(limit - 1))
    assert(limit == 10 ** max_digits) # algorithm works for powers of 10 only
    sum_limit = max_digits * 9 ** 2 + 1
    arrive = [None] * sum_limit
    arrive[1], arrive[89] = 1, 89
    for n in range(2, sum_limit):
        chain = []
        while not arrive[n]:
            chain.append(n)
            n = square_digits(n)
        dest = arrive[n]
        for term in chain:
            arrive[term] = dest
    total = 0
    squares = tuple(i ** 2 for i in range(1, 10))
    for n in range(2, sum_limit):
        if arrive[n] == 89:
            for p in partitions(n, max_digits, squares):
                total += number_count(tuple(sorted(p.values())), 1, max_digits)
    return total
```

As usual, we need to check that this radically new approach computes the right results:

```
>>> all(problem92c(10**i) == problem92d(10**i) for i in range(3, 7))
True
```

Note that since we are using memoization, for fair timing results we must reload the code before running the timer (otherwise we'll get misleadingly fast times due to some of the computation having previously been done and stored in the memoization caches). But with a fresh Python instance:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:problem92d(10**7), number=1)
0.7318389415740967
```

Less than a second! I hope that it's clear now how important the choice of algorithm is. With the piecewise improvement approach the code became about five times faster (which is pretty decent result). But with a better algorithm the code is 250 times faster.

### 4. Questions in comments

You asked some questions in the comments.

1. Obviously in Python 3 you'd use `range`, not `xrange`. And in fact, even in Python 2.7, substituting `xrange` for `range` makes hardly any difference to the runtime (a percent or so), so in my revised answer I've eschewed that.
2. In Python, small integer objects like `1` and `89` are shared and reused:

   ```
   >>> x = 89
   >>> x is 8900 / 100
   True
   ```

   If you look at the source code for [`longobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d5d5b363967e/Objects/longobject.c#l12), you'll see that numbers from `NSMALLNEGINTS` (−5) up to `NSMALLPOSINTS-1` (256) are preallocated in an array. So there is no memory penalty to using them.
3. Iteration works in Python by fetching successive values from an "iterator" object (here the object returned by `range(2, limit)`), not by incrementing the loop variable as you might do in languages like C. So there is no need to be scared about updating the loop variable.
4. Yes, that's right. [Project Euler asks](http://projecteuler.net/problem=92) "How many starting numbers *below* ten million will arrive at 89?" (my emphasis). So it's convenient to use `limit` like this.
5. Probably a copy-paste mistake on my part. I've revised the answer and hopefully the sequence of improvements is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks so much! Some questions: 1. I understand that `xrange()` cannot be used in Python 3? 2. Would storing integers in the list instead of Booleans take up much more memory? 3. Would `n = square_digits(n)` affect the iteration? 4. `range(x, y)` iterates from x to y - 1, so `square_digits(limit)` would be skipped? 5. The `timeit` for 92a is `2.3686327934265137` and the `timeit` for 92b is `3.6810498237609863`. How is that a 25% speedup?

Comment: I wonder if psyco (or similar tools) could speed it up even further.  Though such tools may have a slight warm-up, so they might be ineffective on your final solution.

Comment: @Brian: I find that even allowing for warmup, `problem92d` runs slower in PyPy (about 1.0 s) than in Python 2.7 (about 0.7 s).

Answer (score 3):

## Small Hints

Do away with your `squareDigits()` function — it's time consuming, and performs a lot of work that could be more efficiently derived from results of `squareDigits()` of smaller numbers.

Don't bother distinguishing between `pastChains` and the current `chain` of interest.  In this problem, all chains are the same — given any number, its chain always terminates the same way.  Be like an elephant — never forget the result of any calculation.

## Spoiler alert!

My solution completes in less time than by @GarethRees: 10 seconds on my machine.  The solution relies heavily on memoization.

In particular, computing the sum of the squares of the digits of large numbers is quite time consuming.  My solution never needs to do that: it just adds the square of the ones' digit to previously calculated sum of the squares of the more significant digits.  It also doesn't bother storing any chains; it only needs to keep the furthest known reduced value of each chain.  The reduction procedure also doesn't require any calculation, only array lookups.

```
def euler92(limit):
    # Let sumsq uphold the invariant that the nth element contains
    # the sum of the squares of the digits of n, or better yet, a
    # value somewhere along its reduction chain.

    # Start with the base case: chain[0] = sum(0 * 0) = 0.
    # Also preallocate many unknowns...
    sumsq = [sum((0 * 0,))] + [None] * limit

    # ... and fill them in.  Note how we reuse previous sums!
    for i in xrange(1 + limit):
        sumsq[i] = (i % 10) ** 2 + sumsq[i // 10]

    # Keep reducing each element until everything has converged
    # on either 1 or 89.
    all_converged = False
    while not all_converged:
        all_converged, eighty_nines = True, 0
        for i in xrange(1, 1 + limit):
            if sumsq[i] == 1:
                pass
            elif sumsq[i] == 89:
                eighty_nines += 1
            else:
                all_converged = False
                # sumsq[sumsq[i]] is a quick way to calculate
                # the sum of the squares of the digits, and maybe
                # even skip a few steps down the chain.
                sumsq[i] = sumsq[sumsq[i]]
    return eighty_nines

print euler92(10000000)
```

Comment: Nice! (I find that `sum(0 * 0)` raises `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, but with that fixed, I make this about twice as fast as my `problem92c` — you must have a much faster machine than me.)

Comment: @GarethRees I like that this code is still recognizable as a solution to the original problem. Anyway, I've relaxed my speed claims and fixed the sum(0 * 0) — Thanks!